# How to access serializeArray key/values when key includes square brackets e.g. key[name]

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I am serializing values submitted to a form

```
$(".my-form").submit (event) ->
  values = {}
  $.each $(this).serializeArray(), (i, field) ->
    values[field.name] = field.value
    return
  console.log(values)
```

I now want to access these values, which usually is easy enough.

```
console.log(values.field)
```

However, in this case the form has input names that include square brackets

```
<input name="my_form[content]">
```

What is the correct way to access these values?

`console.log(values)` returns `Object {utf8: "✓", my_form[content]: "my value"}`

But I can't find the correct syntax to get only the `my_form[content]` value.

`console.log(values.my_form[content])` returns `Uncaught ReferenceError: content is not defined`

Comment: Try `values['my_form[content]']`.

Comment: that's the one! thanks @ShaunakD! I had not thought to add the quotes.

Comment: I'll mark this as correct if you post the answer

Comment: No Problem. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the following line

```
values.my_form[content]
```

tries to find a property `my_form` with a key `content`. Where content is considered as variable and found to be undefined.

---

Use `obj['key']` with `''` quotes..

```
values['my_form[content]']
```